av_write_header() doesn't work, throws "Invalid data found when processing input" (error code -1094995529)
I just wrote some basic code to try encoding some sample frames into a file. But before I could even get to that point, the program fails writing the header. If I try to ignore this, or skip writing the header, av_write_frame() segfaults, so I'm assuming both errors are related to I/O.
Here's the code that I'm trying:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

int main() {
   AVFormatContext* formatContext = NULL;
   avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatContext, NULL, NULL, "output.mkv");
   if (!formatContext) {
      return 1;
   }

   const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
   if (!codec) {
      return 1;
   }

   AVStream* stream = avformat_new_stream(formatContext, codec);
   if (!stream) {
      return 1;
   }

   AVCodecContext* codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
   if (!codecContext) {
      return 1;
   }

   codecContext->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
   codecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
   codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
   codecContext->width = 640;
   codecContext->height = 480;
   codecContext->time_base.den = 30;
   codecContext->time_base.num = 1;
   codecContext->gop_size = 30;

   if (avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL) < 0) {
      return 1;
   }

   avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, codecContext);

   if (avio_open(&formatContext->pb, "output.mkv", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
      return 1;
   }

   int h = avformat_write_header(formatContext, NULL);
   if (h < 0) {
      printf("failed to write header: %s (%d)\n",av_err2str(h),h);
      return 1;
   }

   avformat_free_context(formatContext);
   avcodec_free_context(&codecContext);
}

Output:
$ ./a.out
[libx264 @ 0x6468176c52c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x6468176c52c0] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
failed to write header: Invalid data found when processing input (-1094995529)


Related: How can I find out what this ffmpeg error code means?

@WeatherVane 1094995529 corresponds to 'I' 'N' 'D' 'A' (invalid data) that already displayed by av_err2str: "Invalid data found when processing input". In which way this repeating of err2str's job can help to find out what caused "invalid data"?

@yvs2014 it presumably means that the input data is invalid, not the input stream. What else to say? I merely pointed to a duplicate asking the same question. Has OP tried with a different data file?

@DanRafone Supposedly 'mkv' is a container format (taken from filename for avformat_alloc_output_context2()) and not valid for video output format name.
For example with a filename output.mpeg, or explicitly setting some valid format with avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatContext, NULL, "mpeg", "output.mkv"); I think it'll pass without errors. ["mpeg" here is just for demo]
